# iphone read from file

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

i create a view based application , in this project i want read data from .plist file.

how it is possible,

Pleas help me ?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistfilename" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", path]];

NSString *body = [dict objectForKey:@"Keyname"];
```

with the use of this anyone can read data from plist file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the .plist file is a dictionary at root level,

```
return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/your.plist"];
```

otherwise,

```
NSData* plist_data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/your.plist"];
return [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plist_data mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NULL errorDescription:NULL];
```